# How to transfer input type file control from first form to second form and post that second form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using a MVC project and jquery html for posting data. I'm having a specific issue while trying to get the user selected file from 1st form to transfer to 2nd hidden form and submit that 2nd form using Jquery.form.js plugin (using .ajaxForm function).

The scenario is:

- User chooses the image file in 1st form with other details, then submits the form.
- In 1st form, I save the user details.
- Then appends that `<input type ="file"` control to second form and post that 2nd form using .ajaxForm function.

But my controller action is not getting the file stream. File control is appended in 2nd form but not the file. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Here is the code I am using:

In html:

```
<div id="divHiddenUploadForm" class="ui-helper-hidden">
<form id="FrmHiddenToUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("Upload","user")">

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContactId)
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  //using jquery.form plugin
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            target: '#frmEditContact',   // target element(s) to be updated with server
```

response:

```
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: "@ViewBag.ImageUrl",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result); 
        },  // post-submit callback
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        resetForm: true
    };

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
    $('#FrmHiddenToUpload').ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: You cannot handle File Types through AJAX directly. Workarounds are to use Flash or iframe proxy.

Comment: Why not save the image on the first form along with the user details?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with something I was doing.  The result was I wrote a plugin that remembered the files that were uploaded and removed them if the user left without submitting them.  You are welcome to pick it over.  Sorry its single spaced.

```
 /*
 * jQuery FileUpload plugin 1.0
 * Author: Mike Santoro
 *
 * In ordr for the plugin to recreate previews after form submittion the
 * hidden form field must be incuded in the form.
 * The upload button must directly follow the file field.
 * The file field must have the same id and name value.
 * To override the settings on a per field bases use the data- scope.
 *

  maxamount: 1, //maximum number of files to be uploaded
  maxsize: 100, //max filesize in kb
  timoutFactor: 25, //average speed in kb per second
  mimetype: "jpeg,jpg", //file extension to allow
  previewtarget: "div.media", //div to add previews to
  filepath: "dev\\usa\\webportals", //File upload path.  Base path item is evaluated server side valid entries are image and media.
  webroot: "http://devimages.mysite.com/images", \\root image path for display
  loadimage: "/usa/eng/webPortals/zoomloader.gif", //Image to display while uploading.
  deleteimage: "/eng/redRemove.png", //Image to display to remove file.
  webpath: "//inquiry/", //web path to accces images for preview
  fileloadfield: "#ajaxFileUploadFilesList", //file field to store saved images, for use when rebuilding page
  defaulterr: "Your file did not upload.  Please try again.", //default error message for failure from server
  imagepreviewlist: "jpeg,jpg,png,gif", /list of images to preview
  defaultLeaveMessage: "You have uploaded files, if you leave this page your files will be deleted." //message when page is left without sumbmitting the form

 */


;(function($){
 $.fn.fileUpload = function(options){
  var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.fileUpload.defaults, options)
  , initSelector = this;
  loadFiles(settings.fileloadfield);
  remFiles(initSelector);
  cleanFiles(initSelector);
  return initSelector.each(function(index){
   var $obj = $(this),
    $jForm = $obj.parents("form");
   $obj.bind("click.uploadFile", function(event){
    var $obj = $(this),
     jFile = $obj.prevAll("input[type=file]").attr("id"),
     $jFile = $("#" + jFile),
     imagesuploaded = $obj.data("imagesuploaded") || 0,
     uploadFields = [];
     localSettings = $.extend({}, settings, $obj.data());
    if($jFile.val().length > 1){
     uploadFields.push("<span>");
     uploadFields.push("<img style=\"position: absolute;\" src=\"" + localSettings.webroot + localSettings.loadimage + "\" />");
     uploadFields.push("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ajaxFilePath\" id=\"ajaxFilePath\" value=\"" + localSettings.filepath + "\" />");
     uploadFields.push("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ajaxMaxSize\" id=\"ajaxMaxSize\" value=\"" + localSettings.maxsize * 1000 + "\" />");
     uploadFields.push("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ajaxMimeType\" id=\"ajaxMimeType\" value=\"" + localSettings.mimetype + "\" />");
     uploadFields.push("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ajaxFileName\" id=\"ajaxFileName\" value=\"" + $jFile.val() + "\" />");
     uploadFields.push("</span>");
    $obj
     .hide()
     .after(uploadFields.join(""))
      .parent()
       .find(".error")
       .slideUp()
       .remove();
    togButtons();
    $jFile
     .attr("name", jFile);
     $obj
      .data("filelist", ($obj.prev("input[type=hidden]").val() || ""))
       .prev("input[type=hidden]")
       .remove();
    $jForm.bind("submit.upload" + index, function(event){
     var strName = ("uploader" + (new Date()).getTime()),
      jFrame = $("<iframe name=\"" + strName + "\" id=\"" + strName + "\" src=\"about:blank\" />"),
      previewSection = [],
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       errorDisplay($obj, jFrame, "");
       jFrame.unbind("load.frameLoad" + index).remove();
       console.log("timeout");
      }, (localSettings.maxsize || 10000) / localSettings.timoutFactor * 10000);
      console.log('timout in : ' + (localSettings.maxsize || 10000) / localSettings.timoutFactor * 10000);
     jFrame.css("display", "block");
     $("body").append(jFrame);
     jFrame.bind("load.frameLoad" + index, function(event){
      var objUploadBody = $(window[strName].document),
       $jBody = objUploadBody.find("div").is("#json"),
       $objData,
       showMove = {};
      if($jBody){
       $jBody = objUploadBody.find("#json");
       $objData = $.parseJSON($jBody.html());
       if($objData.svrstatus === "0"){
        $obj
        .data("filelist", ($obj.data("filelist") ? $obj.data("filelist") + "*" : "") + ($objData.filereturn || ""))
         .prev("input[type=file]")
         .val("")
        .end()
         .next("span")
         .remove();
        $jFile
         .val("")
         .attr("name", jFile + "FileUploadField");
        $obj.data("imagesuploaded", imagesuploaded + 1);
        if(localSettings.previewtarget.length > 0){
         previewSection.push("<div>");
         if(localSettings.imagepreviewlist.indexOf($objData.serverfileext.toLowerCase()) > 0){
          previewSection.push("<img class=\"removeImg\" data-filename=\"" + $objData.filereturn + "\" src=\"" + localSettings.webroot + localSettings.deleteimage + "\" />");
          previewSection.push("<img class=\"filePreview\" src=\"" + localSettings.webroot + localSettings.webpath + $objData.filereturn + "\" title=\"" + $objData.filereturn + " " + $objData.filesize + "\" />");
          showMove['width'] = "show";
         }
         else{
          previewSection.push("<img class=\"removeFile\" data-filename=\"" + $objData.filereturn + "\" src=\"" + localSettings.webroot + localSettings.deleteimage + "\" />");
          previewSection.push("<div class=\"filePreview\">" + $objData.filereturn + " " + $objData.filesize + "</div>");
          showMove['height'] = "show";
         }
         previewSection.push("</div>");
         $obj
          .nextAll(localSettings.previewtarget + ":first")
          .prepend(previewSection.join(""))
          .find("div:first")
          .hide()
          .animate(showMove);
        }
        togButtons();
        if($obj.data("imagesuploaded") < localSettings.maxamount){
         $obj.show();
        }
        $obj
         .before("<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"fileFieldLists\" name=\"" + jFile + "\" value=\"" + ($obj.data("filelist") || "") + "\" />");
        $(localSettings.fileloadfield).val($("input[type=hidden].fileFieldLists").serialize());
       }
       else{
        errorDisplay($obj, jFrame, $objData);
       }
      }
      else{
       errorDisplay($obj, jFrame, "");
      }
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      jFrame.unbind("load.frameLoad" + index);
      setTimeout(function(){jFrame.remove();},100);
     });
     $jForm
      .attr({action: "index.cfm?action=santoro.fileUploadAJAX&_nhd&fileField=" + jFile,
       method: "post",
       enctype: "multipart/form-data",
       encoding: "multipart/form-data",
       target: strName});
     });
     $jForm.trigger("submit.upload" + index);
     $jForm.unbind("submit.upload" + index).attr("target", "");
    }
    else{
     $jFile.trigger("click");
    }
   }); /// end click
  });//end each
  function togButtons(){
   $(initSelector).each(function(){
    var $obj = $(this);
    $obj.attr("disabled", ($obj.attr("disabled") ? false : true));
   });
  }
  function cleanFiles(obj){
   var $obj = $(obj),
   $jForm = $obj.parents("form");
   $jForm
    .find("input[type=button],input[onclick*=Submit],input[value*=Submit],input[value*=Save],input[type=submit]")
    .not($obj)
    .bind("click.save mouseup.save", function(event){
     $(window).unbind('beforeunload.cleanFile unload.removeFiles');
    });
   $(window).bind('beforeunload.cleanFile', function(event){
    var localSettings = $.extend({}, settings),
    filesList = "";
    $("input[type=hidden].fileFieldLists").each(function(){
     var $obj = $(this);
     filesList += ($obj.val() || "");
    });
    $(window).bind('unload.removeFiles', function(event){
     var filesList = [];
     $("input[type=hidden].fileFieldLists").each(function(){
      var $obj = $(this),
       localSettings = $.extend({}, settings, $obj.next().data()),
       fieldValues = ($obj.val().indexOf("*") ? $obj.val().split("*") : $obj.val()),
       fieldValuesCnt = fieldValues.length;
       for(var i = 0; i < fieldValuesCnt; i++){
        filesList.push(localSettings.filepath + fieldValues[i]);
       }
     });
     if(filesList.length){
      deleteFiles(filesList.join(","), false);
     }
    });
    if(filesList.length){
     return localSettings.defaultLeaveMessage;
    }
   });
  }
  function deleteFiles(fileList, cleaner){
   var ajaxOptions = {
    url: "index.cfm?action=santoro.fileDeleteAJAX",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"fileList":fileList},
    timeout: 5000,
    dataType: "json",
    async : cleaner || false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {console.log(data)}
    };
   $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
  }
  function errorDisplay($obj, jFrame, $objData){
   var localSettings = $.extend({}, settings, $obj.data()),
    errText = $objData.errtext || localSettings.defaulterr,
    jFile = $obj.prevAll("input[type=file]").attr("id");
   $obj
    .show()
    .before("<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"fileFieldLists\" name=\"" + jFile + "\" value=\"" + ($obj.data("filelist") || "") + "\" />")
     .next("span")
     .remove()
    .end()
    .after("<div class=\"error hidden ajaxError\">" + errText + "</div>")
     .next(".error")
     .removeClass("hidden")
     .slideDown("slow");
   setTimeout(function(){jFrame.remove()},100);
   togButtons();
  }
  function remFiles(obj){
   obj.each(function(){
    var $obj = $(this),
     localSettings = $.extend({}, settings, $obj.data());
    $obj.nextAll(localSettings.previewtarget).first().delegate("img.removeImg, img.removeFile", "click", function(){
     var $remObj = $(this),
      re = new RegExp("\\*?" + $remObj.data("filename"), "g"),
      hideMove = {};
      hideMove[($remObj.hasClass("removeImg")? "width" : "height")] = "hide";
     $remObj
      .parent("div")
      .animate(
       hideMove
       , 200
       , function(){
        $(this).remove();
       }
      );
     $obj.data("imagesuploaded", $obj.data("imagesuploaded") - 1).show();
     $obj
     .prevAll("input[type=hidden]:first")
      .val(function(){
       return $(this).val().replace(re, "");
      });
      $(localSettings.fileloadfield).val($("input[type=hidden].fileFieldLists").serialize());
      deleteFiles(localSettings.filepath + $remObj.data("filename"), true);
    });
   });
  }
  function loadFiles(obj){
   $(obj).each(function(){
    var $obj = $(this),
     $loadedFiles = $obj.val().split("&"),
     fieldCnt = $loadedFiles.length,
     fieldSplit,
     fieldValuesCnt = 0,
     $ajaxObj,
     fieldValues,
     isImage = false,
     localSettings,
     re = new RegExp("\\+", "g"),
     previewSection = [];
    if($obj.val().length > 1){
     for(var i = 0; i < fieldCnt; i++){
      fieldSplit = $loadedFiles[i].split("=");
      $ajaxObj = $("#" + fieldSplit[0]).next("input[type=button]");
      fieldValues = (fieldSplit[0].indexOf("*") ? fieldSplit[1].split("*") : fieldSplit[1]);
      fieldValuesCnt = fieldValues.length;
      localSettings = $.extend({}, settings, $ajaxObj.data()),
      previewSection = [];
      $ajaxObj
      .data({filelist: fieldSplit[1],
        imagesuploaded: fieldValuesCnt
        })
       .prevAll("input[type=file]:first")
        .attr("name", fieldSplit[0] + "FileUploadField")
       .end()
       .before("<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"fileFieldLists\" name=\"" + fieldSplit[0] + "\" value=\"" + unescape(fieldSplit[1].replace(re, " ")) + "\" />");
      if(fieldValuesCnt >= localSettings.maxamount){
       $ajaxObj.hide();
      }
      for(var j = 0; j < fieldValuesCnt; j++){
       isImage = fieldValues[j].split(".");
       fieldValue = unescape(fieldValues[j].replace(re, " "));
       previewSection = [];
       if(fieldValue.length > 0){
        previewSection.push("<div>");
        if(localSettings.imagepreviewlist.indexOf(isImage[1].toLowerCase()) > 0){
         previewSection.push("<img class=\"removeImg\" data-filename=\"" + fieldValue + "\" src=\"" + localSettings.webroot + localSettings.deleteimage + "\" />");
         previewSection.push("<img class=\"filePreview\" src=\"" + localSettings.webroot + localSettings.webpath + fieldValue + "\" title=\"" + fieldValue + "\" />");
        }
        else{
         previewSection.push("<img class=\"removeFile\" data-filename=\"" + fieldValue + "\" src=\"" + localSettings.webroot + localSettings.deleteimage + "\" />");
         previewSection.push("<div class=\"filePreview\">" + fieldValue + "</div>");
        }
        previewSection.push("</div>");
        $ajaxObj
         .nextAll(localSettings.previewtarget)
         .first()
         .prepend(previewSection.join(""));
       }
      }
     }
     $(localSettings.fileloadfield).val($("input[type=hidden].fileFieldLists").serialize());
    }
   });
  }
 };
 $.fn.fileUpload.defaults = {
  maxamount: 1,
  maxsize: 100,
  timoutFactor: 25,
  mimetype: "jpeg,jpg",
  previewtarget: "div.media",
  filepath: "image\\usa\\",
  webroot: "http://devimages.mysite.com/usa",
  loadimage: "/eng/zoomloader.gif",
  deleteimage: "/eng/redRemove.png",
  webpath: "/inquiry/",
  fileloadfield: "#ajaxFileUploadFilesList",
  defaulterr: "Your file did not upload.  Please try again.",
  imagepreviewlist: "jpeg,jpg,png,gif",
  defaultLeaveMessage: "You have uploaded files, if you leave this page your files will be deleted."
 };
})(jQuery);
```